# Assigning elements to one array in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a np.array as one of the values associated with a key. I am trying to change the values in a particular array of only one of the dictionaries in the list and am finding that each dictionary in the list gets changed.

```
tmp_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
BF = [{ 'temp':78, 'nums':tmp_array},{'tmp':61,'nums':temp_array}]
BF[0]['nums'][0,0] = 44
```

This reassigns every dictionary in the list BF and returns

```
[{'temp': 78, 'nums': array([[44,  2],[ 3,  4]])},
 {'temp': 61, 'nums': array([[44,  2],[ 3,  4]])}]
```

I was expecting only the first dictionary to be changed, but all of the dictionaries in the list (BF) were changed.

Is there a way to assign change the values of only one of the dictionaries? (I know I can assign a new value to the dictionary, but it does not appear to work if the values if an array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy arrays are mutable objects, and you're using the same object in the different dictionaries. Since it's the same object, changing it anywhere will change it everywhere.

One fix would be to make a copy for each new dictionary:

```
tmp_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
BF = [{ 'temp':78, 'nums':tmp_array.copy()},{'tmp':61,'nums':tmp_array.copy()}]
BF[0]['nums'][0,0] = 44
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I now understand and can move forward.

Comment: Glad to help. Please hit the check mark to choose the answer as accepted if it was helpful (or wait a bit first to see if someone posts a better answer.)